# Android platform tool is not getting installed

Tags: android-studio, android-studio-2.2

I am getting the following output while updating Android Studio

```
Installing Android SDK Platform-tools, revision 25.0.3
Stopping ADB server failed (code -1).
Unzip failed: F:\Android\platform-tools\adb.exe (Access is denied)
Done. Nothing was installed.
```

Because of this ADB is not starting

Answer (score 0):

The PlatForm tools should be installed when android studio is closed.